# LEFT JOIN to same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to derive monthly subtotals for client accounts and if the client has no activity for the month, it will return 0.  There is a billing_month field in the table which contains every month; even if the customer didn't have activity, another customer would.  I wanted to do a left join on the table so that every billing_month would show up but that's not working.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT COALESCE (SUM(b.Adjusted_Price), 0) AS Amount, a.Billing_Month,    
dbo.tblSubaccounts.Master_Account_Name
FROM dbo.tblBilling_Detail AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblBilling_Detail AS b ON a.ID = b.ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblSubaccounts ON 
dbo.tblSubaccounts.ID = b.Linked_Account
GROUP BY a.Billing_Month, dbo.tblSubaccounts.Master_Account_Name
```

Sample Data - Note that customer 2 (the customer ID) has no data for May so I would want May to return 0.

```
ID  Billing_Month   Adjusted_Price  Linked_Account
1      3/1/14        100            2
2      4/1/14        200            2
3      5/1/14        300            3
```

Comment: can you paste some sample data??

Comment: I posted some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select coalesce(sum(detail.Adjusted_Price),0) Amount
, months.Billing_Month
, accounts.Master_AccountName
from (
    select distinct Billing_Month
    from dbo.tblBilling_Detail 
) months
cross join dbo.tblSubaccounts  accounts --cross join so we have a combination of all months & accounts
left outer join dbo.tblBilling_Detail detail 
    on detail.Linked_Account = accounts.id
    and detail.Billing_Month = months.Billing_Month
group by months.Billing_Month
, accounts.Master_AccountName
```

The issue with yours was you were joining the billing detail table on its id; which means you pulled back the same record twice (i.e. one record from A and the same record from B).  This meant that if you didn't have a record for a given month/account combo, you wouldn't get it from this approach.

Above I've taken the distinct list of months and cross joined with accounts to ensure we have one record for each account/month combo.  I then left joined this with the detail table so that we can pull back accounting info where it exists; group & sum are as per your original; i.e. ensuring we summarise the data into one row for each account/month combo.

Comment: Thank you!  That did the trick!  Side note:  I added "FROM" into your solution in case you want to edit it.

Comment: Oops - sorry, hadn't run it to check for typos; thanks.